# TortoiseSVN revert to a revision only on svn and keep changes locally

Tags: tortoisesvn, revert

How can I revert to the previous revision on TortoiseSVN, but the keep the last changes on my local working copy?

Comment: I suggest moving this to [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Tools used in development (like tortoisesvn and subversion) are on-topic

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: Following that logic, questions on how to use Inkscape and Gimp would be on-topic here, as well, because they are used by developers to design icons and in-app graphics.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I refer you to the [help center: "On Topic"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) : _"software tools commonly used by programmers;"_ And I'd argue that inkscape and gimp don't fall under that definition, because then you are not working as a programmer, but a graphic designer (even if you **are** a programmer).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: And when writing a scientific paper that is stored in an SVN repository, I am not working as a programmer, but as a researcher and/or writer (even if I **am** a programmer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [the solution](https://superuser.com/questions/72497/svn-revert-changes-in-repository-but-not-locally) on [Super User](https://superuser.com/). I tried to flag the question as a duplicate, but it seems the duplicate needs to be on stackoverflow. Considering there are other questions on `TortoiseSVN` on SO, I'll post the answer here.

What I had to do is checkout a new repo copy of the revision I wanted to revert to, merge the range of following revisions up to head revision, commit and then delete the copy.

Comment: You can either flag the question as off-topic while selecting that it's a better fit for Super User (and then close it as a duplicate there), or delete the question altogether.